# File is saved to /tmp directory, despite setting it permanent

Tags: 7, files

I have a form, where I can upload a file:

```
function policies_edit_form($form, &$form_state, $data_array = NULL)
{
  ...
  $form['file'] = array(
        "#title" => "Document file",
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#size' => 22,
        );
  ...
}

function policies_edit_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
   $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
           'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx'),
                                 ));
   if ($file) {
        // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
        $form_state['values']['file'] = $file;
    }
}

function policies_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
  if($form_state['values']['file'] != '')
  {
    $form_state['values']['file']->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    $file = file_save($form_state['values']['file']);
  }
}
```

Despite I set the status to FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT, the file is uploaded to /tmp directory. After the upload is done, bash commands give this:

```
bash-4.2$ cd /tmp
bash-4.2$ ls -la 1_1.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apache apache 111531 Sep 16 16:06 1_1.pdf
```

And "temporary://" folder in the database:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM file_managed;
+-----+-----+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+------------+
| fid | uid | filename | uri                 | filemime        | filesize | status | timestamp  |
+-----+-----+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+------------+
|   2 |   1 | 1.pdf    | temporary://1_1.pdf | application/pdf |   111531 |      1 | 1379333217 |
+-----+-----+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------+------------+
```

How can I upload it to public://policies/ folder? Should I manually set $form_state['values']['file']->uri or there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [managed file element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file), it's much easier:

```
$form['fid'] = array(
  "#title" => "Document file",
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#size' => 22,
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx'),
  ),
);
```

Then remove the validation handler and change you submit handler to:

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['fid']);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
```

And you're done; Drupal handles moving the temp file into the right place for you, as well as adding relevant records to the `file_managed`/`file_usage` tables.

Comment: In drupal 8 it appears that the managed file element still works along with #upload_location and #upload_validators but you are required to add the PERM status on the file and ->add() the file usage yourself to avoid temp file deletion on cron and properly document usage. Cheers!